# Azure Web App FTP 550 Access Denied

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to use FTP to upload specific files (not a full release) to an Azure Web App. Essentially I am using a PowerShell script to FTP files up to the web app in Azure. I can add new files, create files and folders but when I try to overwrite or delete a file, I get a 550 Access is denied.

I tried creating a a new deployment credential and was able to log in but the result was the same when trying to delete anything; 550 Access is Denied.

Is there any way to grant more permissions to this user or is this impossible? Thanks!

Comment: Can you check if your firewall is blocked outgoing FTP writes?

Comment: Make sure you're not trying to write to a read-only file

Comment: There is no firewall blocking outgoing requests, and the files aren't read only either. I am able to change the file names with no problem. So for example, I can change the web.config file to web.config.bak and this works fine. Its only when I try to delete or overwrite a file that I get the error. Also, if I FTP files that don't already exist in the directory, it works fine. So this really kind of eliminates both of these as a possible issue.

Comment: Try using KUDU tool to achieve this and see if it works and try connect FTP host name not FTPS hostname e.g ftp:// not ftps:// because protocols are different

Answer (score 5):

You **can't** overwrite runnig app. Stop the app first, then upload, then start app again. You can stop/start the app from azure portal or using `az` cli

```
az webapp stop --name %AZURE_APP% --resource-group %AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP%
```

and

```
az webapp start --name %AZURE_APP% --resource-group %AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP%
```

p.s.: Funny thing is that you **can** delete running app. Then you still can't upload the running app even when it's already deleted.

Comment: This exactly happened to me from devOps pipeline. I used to deploy my website just by running the pipeline, I never had the issue of stopping the website first and then deploy. But this worked for at least this time.

Answer (score 5):

Check that you are not using the READ ONL FTP URL.

The publish profile gives two FTP url's the bottom on is ready only and will always give a 550 error.

Answer (score 4):

550 Denied error, it indicates that you have no enough permission to do that.

You could download the Azure publish profile to get ftp user and password.
You also could follow  this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp#get-ftp-connection-information) to get FTP information.

**or**

As zahid Faroq mentioned that you could use KUDU tool(https://{yoursite}.scm.azurewebsites.net) to do that easily. For more information about KUDU, please refer to this [document](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)

If you still can reproduce the issue, I recommand that you could [create a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to get help from Azure team.

Comment: Tom, the answer was the permissions on the files themselves in Azure. I was able to use KUDU (as suggested) to change the permissions on the files, at which point I was then able to upload the files without issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the server, then I could delete/alter the app.